# ZOQL date filtering via Zuora REST API

Tags: rest, python-requests, zuora, zuora-soap

I'm trying to establish some pipelines that would pull data from Zuora, however, I want them to be incremental, i.e. so that only the data that has been updated after the last load to be pulled. In order to do that, I access `https://rest.zuora.com/query/jobs`, passing an object like this:

```
{
  "compression": "NONE",
  "output": {
    "target": "S3"
  },
  "outputFormat": "CSV",
  "query": "select something from somewhere where updatedDate > {some_date}"
}
```

The problem is whenever I include any sort of date filtering, the outcome is always the same: `Error code: LINK_0000003A. Query failed (#some_number): line 1:41: Cannot apply operator: timestamp(3) with time zone <= varchar(19)`
I even tried running an example query posted somewhere in Zuora Export ZOQL documentation, to no avail. As an additional piece of information, I'm using Python's `requests` library to do so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `{some_date}`. Now it's just a string (varchar), and you're trying to compare it with `timestamp(3) with time zone`.

Probably something like this:

```
{
  "compression": "NONE",
  "output": {
    "target": "S3"
  },
  "outputFormat": "CSV",
  "query": "select something from somewhere where updatedDate > TIMESTAMP {some_date}"
}
```

Just added the `TIMESTAMP` before the date, as far as I know that is enough in ZOQL.